# trying to move lines 1-10 of a csv to a JSON file. I seem to only be getting the 10th line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python and attempting to add lines 1-10 of a csv into a JSON file, however, I only seem to be getting the 10th line of the CSV. I can't seem to figure out what is incorrect about my argument. Any help appcreated!

```
import csv, json, itertools

csvFilePath = "example.csv"
jsonFilePath = "example.json"

    # Read the CSV and add data to a dictionary
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), 0,10):
            data = csvRow

print(data)


    #Write the data to a JSON file
    with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `data = csvRow`, the `data` variable keeps getting overwritten, so at the end only the last line you read will be inside `data`. Try something like this:

```
import csv, json, itertools

csvFilePath = "example.csv"
jsonFilePath = "example.json"

# Read the CSV and add data to a dictionary
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        for csvRow in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(csvFile), 0,10):
            #email = csvRow["email"]
            data[len(data)] = csvRow

print(data)

# Write the data to a JSON file
with open(jsonFilePath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(line, indent=4))
```

(Didn't test this, but the idea is to add `csvRow` as new elements of the dict `data`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input CSV is

```
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
```

We have the following code:

```
import json
import csv

inpf = open("test.csv", "r")
csv_reader = csv.reader(inpf)

# here you slice the columns with [2:4] for example
lines = [row[2:4] for row in csv_reader]
inpf.close()


lines_json = json.dumps(lines)
outpf = open("out.json", "w")
outpf.write(lines_json)
outpf.close()
```

which creates

```
[
  [
    "3",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "c",
    "d"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `data` dictionary in your loop through the file.

```
CSV_FILE_PATH = "example.csv"

with open(CSV_FILE_PATH) as myfile:
    # You might set a key for each index as you loop:
    data = {i: next(myfile) for i in range(10)}
print(data)
```